# node glob sync returns empty array

Tags: node.js, windows, glob

I am using glob nodejs module to sync files using patterns

I did :

```
 glob.sync('C:\Users\maroodb\project\config\*.json')
```

but it returns : `[]` such the config folders contains 15 files *.json

is there a problem with windows path ?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, a windows path will not work. A glob pattern is always in POSIX format. You just have to change the separator:

```
glob.sync('C:/Users/maroodb/project/config/*.json');
```

If the path is dynamic, you have to replace the separator:

```
glob.sync('C:\Users\maroodb\project\config\*.json'.replace(/\\/g, '/'))
```

Comment: Damn, this solved it! I was using `fast-glob` & it gave me this issue. Funnily enough the docs have the answer too https://github.com/mrmlnc/fast-glob#how-to-write-patterns-on-windows

Comment: Shame it doesn't detect the OS, all those packages using this library and each one of them having to write replacement code. Hmm.